# script16386 no such interface supported error in IE9 browser

Tags: internet-explorer-9

We are using IE8 for our apps till now. Recently got an upgradation needed to IE9 browser.
The features are not working properly in IE9. When I select a radio button, based on that a button should be enabled. But it is not happening in IE9 browser.
Also I observe the java script error "script16386 no such i nterface supported" is coming when I click the radio button. Hope this java script error is causing the issue.
My application is a JSF application. And the app will be called from inside an IFrame tag.
I googled for all possible solutions but no progress.
Replaced the Richfaces-impl, richfaces-ui, richfaces-api jars from 3.3.2.SR1 to 3.3.3 version. Didn't work.
Also followed the below steps in the link : http://vsomani.blogspot.com/2011/12/a4j-and-ie-9-issues-with.html -- Didn't work :(
The project is an ANT project.
Can anyone help on this. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not providing a fix but a workaround that you can try.

Use the fallback mechanism to IE 8, add the following meta tag.

meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"

Comment: This meta tag fixes indeed several IE problems so everybody already uses it. However, it did not fix this particular error. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. For me, the Error occured in line 1402 of AJAX.js, where window.document.importNode is called.

IE9 support for importNode seems to be incomplete, and throws an error for some DOM documents.

I patched the AJAX.js further, and in line 495 i replaced:

```
if((typeof(document.importNode) == "undefined") && Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE){
```

by

```
if((typeof(document.importNode) == "undefined") && Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE || Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE9 ){
```

It seems to solve the problem for me. This Change defines the Sarissa importNode-by-hand for IE9 , too.

Answer (score 0):

As vsomani stated, it's a **IE9 bug**. Just add this line to the header of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and could trace it to this Javascript source line that worked just fine with Firefox and Chrome:

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "File");
```

According to the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument) this call has an *optional* 3rd argument. However, the IE dev tools console says that an argument is missing that is not optional.

These two experiments, trying to meaningfully fill the 3rd argument, did NOT work:

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "File", "text/xml");
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "File", "");
```

The IE dev tools console error message on these to attempted fixes was: **script16386 no such interface**.

The fix was to explicitly fill the 3rd argument to null:

```
var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "File", null);
```

No idea what the relation is with the text of the error message, though. Googling on the script number did not show info from microsoft.com.

By the way, my app is to control a top-notch 60.000 euro laboratory device, and I am really scratching my head why we should stick to the standard windows builtin IE browser instead of selecting an equally top-notch performing browser like Chrome or Explorer. I should not have to spend all this time fixing IE problems.